# How to get texture dimensions with Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

I would like to know wether it is possible to get the dimensions of a texture ? 
I used this line to set my texture :

```
const texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(src)
```

Maybe it is necessary to load the image to get its dimensions (but is it possible only with javascript, not html and its div ?) ?

I would like the material I create afterwards to fit the texture dimensions.

Comment: What format image are you loading?

Comment: I'm using a mapping web service, so I don't know the format (its not in the URL I use to load the image)

Comment: You should be able to get that information from the mapping service, either through their documentation, or by downloading an image manually and examining its format yourself.

Answer (score 7):

First, `THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture` is deprecated in the latest THREE.js (r90). Take a look at [`THREE.TextureLoader`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/loaders/TextureLoader) instead.

That said, you can get to the image and its properties from a loaded texture.

```
texture.image
```

Depending on the image format, you should be able to access the `width`/`height` properties, which will be your texture's dimensions.

Just a note: Loading a texture is asynchronous, so you'll need to define the `onLoad` callback.

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var texture = loader.load( "./img.png", function ( tex ) {
    // tex and texture are the same in this example, but that might not always be the case
    console.log( tex.image.width, tex.image.height );
    console.log( texture.image.width, texture.image.height );
} );
```

Comment: I've already tried using TextureLoader, and it does not work for me. It seems the image is not read, so I end up with a white object. That's why I decided to use ImageUtils, for which the property image is also empty but displays the texture. The field Image is 'undefined' but there is information for the field 'sourceFile'.

Comment: Can you post a snippet ?

Comment: It could be a good idea to check `.naturalWidth` and `.naturalHeight` instead of `.height` and `.width` because natural height / width is guaranteed to contain the actual image size and `.width` / `.height` do not (at least under some circumstances, it's better to be safe): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/naturalHeight

Comment: It's worth noting that the texture returned from the call to `TextureLoader.load()` will possibly not contain the image yet. Whereas within the callback function it does. This is because of the asynchronous nature of the `load()` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn off sizeAttenuation, and you have a function that scales the Sprite according to the desired width, then this function will be like:

```js
scaleWidth(width) {
     const tex = sprite.material.map;
     const scaleY = tex.image.height / tex.image.width;
     sprite.scale.setX(width).setY(width * scaleY);
}
```

So, at this point, you can set the scale according to the desired width, maintaining the aspectRatio of the image.

Then you must have a function that receives the camera, and depending on the type of camera, updates the sprite's width:

```js
updateScale(cam) {
     let cw = 1;
     if(cam.isOrthographicCamera) {
         cw = cam.right - cam.left;
     }
     else if(cam.isPerspectiveCamera) {
         cw = 2 * cam.aspect * Math.tan(cam.fov * 0.5 * 0.01745329);
     }
     scaleWidth(cw * desiredScaleFactor);
}
```